# Taylor expansion in C++: function factory?

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function, taylor-series

In some application I need to have access to the elements of some polynomial expansion (for example `x^i` for `i = 0,1,...`). My idea was to create a "function factory" like

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

std::function<double(double)> Taylor(unsigned int i)
{
    return [i](double y) {return std::pow(y, i);};
}

int main()
{   
    unsigned int n = 3; // the wanted degree in your polynomial basis
    auto f = Taylor(n);
    double a = f(3);
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the example above, we would get the output `a = 27`.

This would be useful in the context of function estimation (i.e., roughly, find the coefficients of some polynomial expansion given data).

Is there some better way to do this? Also, if the polynomial basis is not just `x^i` but something more complicated, using a lambda function could be inappropriate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++, long before lambdas were added to it, has always had a solution for this:
Just implement a class with an `operator()`, so that instances become callables, i.e. useful as functions. We call such objects *functors*.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
// Just an interface base class – not strictly necessary
class realmap {
public:
  virtual double operator()(double parameter) = 0;
  virtual ~operator();
};

class identity : public realmap {
  double operator()(double parameter) override { return parameter; }
};
class twice : public realmap {
  double operator()(double parameter) override { return 2 * parameter; }
};

class monomial : public realmap {
private:
  const unsigned int exponent;

public:
  monomial(unsigned int exponent) : exponent(exponent) {}
  double operator()(double parameter) override {
    double result = 1;
    for (unsigned int pot = 0; pot < exponent; ++pot) {
      result *= parameter;
    }
    return result;
  }
};

int main() {
  auto cube = monomial(3);
  std::cout << cube(1.3) << std::endl;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<realmap>> operations;
  operations.emplace_back(new twice());
  operations.emplace_back(new monomial(2));
  operations.emplace_back(new twice());
  operations.emplace_back(new monomial(3));
  double value = 3.141;
  for (auto &operation : operations) {
    value = (*operation)(value);
  }
  // now is [(3.141 * 2)²·2]³
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: as clean as it can be

Comment: the good thing about the (abstract) base class is you can now contain operations in containers, or write an operation that in itself is composed of interchangeable operations.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<realmap` uses `std::default_deleter<realmap>` which will call the non-virtual `realmap::~realmap`. I think you want a virtual dtor.

Comment: @MSalters yep, -Wpedantic reminds me of that too. At first I didn't want to overload the reader, but I should prolly fix that.

Comment: The *terminus technicus* is "functor". Perhaps add that bit to the asnwer, as that is how you google for it successfully later on.

Comment: @DevSolar yep, done